# gh-pages deployment breaks image links. Common solutions ruled out

Tags: reactjs, github, http-status-code-404, web-deployment, github-pages

I'm having a fairly well-documented problem, but I have implemented all the solutions I've found, and nothing works. The site is using React. I've wondered if React router dom is causing an issue.

When I built my site for deployment on gh-pages, the images broke locally and online at [Open Art Github Pages](https://grismund.github.io/home).
Repo here: [Open Art Repo](https://github.com/Grismund/openartreact)

After searching for hours, I fixed the local issue by adding a .env file to my root folder which contains `PUBLIC_URL="."`. But I have not found a solution to the gh-pages problem. The console logs 404 errors for the images.

The code for the carousel items can be found in: src>components>homeComponenets>CarouselLg.js and CarouselXs.js
The code for the logo can be found here: src>components>HeaderComponent.js

Here are the common solutions I have ruled out:

- Case sensitivity in filename and extension. I left one all caps as a test case. But none show up correctly.
- Wrong file path. I'm quite certain this is not the problem because the files load fine locally.
- Removing "/" before path names.
- Making sure there are no "_" in file names.

I'm also getting a manifest.json 404 error in the console.

Let me know what you think.